# Show that $\Bbb S^2-\{p,q\}$ is diffeomorphic to a cylinder

Tags: real-analysis, manifolds

> Show that $\Bbb S^2-\{p,q\}$ is diffeomorphic to $\Bbb R×\Bbb S^1$.

We have to show that there exists a differentiable bijective application with inverse differentiable between these two sets. Note that we can take $p$ and $q$ to be the north and south poles of the sphere. I could not find such a function. Anybody know?

Comment: Think visually. If you delete the north and south pole from a sphere, then you can just expand it outwards horizontally to the cylinder $S^1\times(-1,1)$, and then from there to $S^1\times \Bbb R$.

Comment: Okay. Visually I can see that. I wanted to display this diffeomorphism

Comment: Write down the formula for the function $ S^2\setminus\{(0,0,\pm1)\}\to S^1\times(-1,1). $

Comment: The word you want is _map_, not "application." The English word "application" means something else entirely.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: if $(x,y,z)\in S^2\setminus\{(0,0,±1)\}$, $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1$ by definition. The obvious projection gives the third coordinate:
$$(x,y,z)\longmapsto(u,v,z).$$
You want $(u,v)$ proportional to $(x,y)$ and $u^2 + v^2 = 1$. You have $0 < x^2+y^2\le 1$ (why the first inequality?)...